# How can I implement updating the value of a variable every second

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my code there is a variable which is assigned a random array value. My code on SwiftUI.

My array:

```
let bannerAdArrey = [1, 2]
```

My variable:

```
private let randarrBanner: Int = bannerAdArrey.randomElement()!
```

How can I make it so that the value of this variable is updated every second or 10 seconds, so that the value of this code changes:

```
if randarrBanner == 1 {
  YandexBanner() .frame(width: 360, height: 50)
} else if randarrBanner == 2 {
   MyTargetBanner() .frame(width: 360, height: 50)
}
```

Comment: A Timer is one solution but you should add some more context to your question, for instance you have tagged the question with SwiftUI so perhaps explain how that is relevant.

Comment: What do you want to update? Just change the value in your variable? Notify code that depends on the variable that it has changed? Update your UI?

Comment: I want update value in my variable, and notify code that depends on the variable that it has changed. This is need to change after 10 or more seconds: if randarrBanner == 1 {
                    YandexBanner() .frame(width: 360, height: 50)
                } else if randarrBanner == 2 {
                    MyTargetBanner() .frame(width: 360, height: 50)
                }

Comment: You can also user TimelineView and update it periodically https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you. I did it that:

```
let bannerAdArrey = [1, 2]

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var timer : Timer?
    
    @State private var randarrBanner: Int = bannerAdArrey.randomElement()!
    
    @State private var randarrBanner1: Int = bannerAdArrey.randomElement()!

var body: some View {

ZStack {

VStack {
                
                if randarrBanner == 1 {
                    YandexBanner() .frame(width: 360, height: 50)
                } else if randarrBanner == 2 {
                    MyTargetBanner() .frame(width: 360, height: 50)
                }

               Spacer()
           
            if randarrBanner1 == 1 {
                YandexBanner() .frame(width: 360, height: 50)
            } else if randarrBanner1 == 2 {
                MyTargetBanner() .frame(width: 360, height: 50)
            }

}

}
.onAppear(perform: delayText)

}

private func delayText() {
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 7.0 ,
        repeats: true, block: { timer in
            randarrBanner = bannerAdArrey.randomElement()!
            randarrBanner1 = bannerAdArrey.randomElement()!
        })
       }
```

Comment: What's the point of `randarrBanner1`? It's not used anywhere. What's the point of using an array with the numbers 1 and 2? Why not simply use `Bool.random()` to show one banner or the other?

Comment: Sorry. The answer was not complete. Changed.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).